# How to allocate memory for time_t in a string in C

Tags: c, string, data-structures, time, struct

I'm trying to build a string that will go into a logfile with this format: "Executable: Time:... Error: ...". However, I am having trouble allocating for my time variable in my data structure. I have been able to code it so that the time can go before the string later but I cannot figure out how to have the time be between the executable and the error message. If anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong I'd appreciate it.

**Code:**

**log.h**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct data_struct
{
  time_t time;
  char *string;
} data_t;

int addmsg(data_t data, char *arg0);
void clearlog(void);
char *getlog(void);
int savelog(char *filename);
```

**loglib.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include "log.h"

//Basic template from Excercise 2.13
typedef struct list_struct
{
  data_t item;
  struct list_struct *next;
} log_t;

static log_t *headPtr = NULL;
static log_t *tailPtr = NULL;

//Like book example with add on for executable name
int addmsg(data_t data, char *arg0)
{
  log_t *newnode;
  int nodesize;
  char timeString[] = ": Time: ";
  char errorString[] = " Error: ";

  //Allocate size for "Executable: time: Error: "
  nodesize = sizeof(log_t) + strlen(data.string) + strlen(arg0) + sizeof(time_t) + strlen(timeString) + strlen(errorString) + 1;
  if((newnode = (log_t *)(malloc(nodesize))) == NULL)
  {
    perror("Malloc failed: ");
    return -1;
  }

  //Makes string "Executable: time: Error: "


  newnode->item.time = data.time;
  char *timeCode = ctime(&newnode->item.time);
  newnode->item.string = (char *)newnode + sizeof(log_t);
  strcpy(newnode->item.string, arg0);
  newnode->item.string = strcat(newnode->item.string, timeString);
  newnode->item.string = strcat(newnode->item.string, timeCode);
  newnode->item.string = strcat(newnode->item.string, errorString);
  newnode->item.string = strcat(newnode->item.string, data.string);
  newnode->next = NULL;

  //Puts string as EOF
  if(headPtr == NULL)
  {
    headPtr = newnode;
  }
  else
  {
    tailPtr->next = newnode;
  }

  tailPtr = newnode;

  return 0;
}

//Clears log
void clearlog(void)
{
  log_t *nextPtr = headPtr;
  //Loop through and clear the log
  while(nextPtr != NULL)
  {
    nextPtr = headPtr->next;
    free(headPtr);
    headPtr = nextPtr;
  }
}

char *getlog(void)
{
  int size = 1;//Set to 1 because of null terminator
  int entryNum = 0; //Number of error logs
  log_t *node = headPtr; //Start at beggining
  char *wholeLog = NULL; //Used to return the entire log
  char *entryString = NULL;

  //Get size
  while(node != NULL)
  {
    entryNum++;
    size += strlen(node->item.string);
    node = node->next;
  }

  //Memory allocation
  wholeLog = malloc(sizeof(char)*(size + 1 + (entryNum * 2)));
  if(wholeLog == NULL)
  {
    perror("Malloc failed: ");
    return NULL;
  }

  //Reset node to beggining
  node = headPtr;

  //Builds the entire log to return
  while(node != NULL)
  {
    entryString = strcat(entryString, node->item.string);
    wholeLog = strcat(wholeLog, entryString);
    wholeLog = strcat(wholeLog, "\n"); //New line
    node = node->next;
  }

  //Make space
  wholeLog += (strlen(wholeLog) - size - (entryNum-1));

  return wholeLog;

}

int savelog(char *filename)
{
  FILE *f;
  char *logPrinter;
  f = fopen(filename, "a");
  if(!f)
  {
    perror("Error opening file: ");
    return -1;
  }

  //Get the log to print
  logPrinter = getlog();

  if(logPrinter == NULL)
  {
    printf("Empty Log\n");
    return 0;
  }

  fprintf(f, "%s\n", logPrinter);
  fclose(f);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your use of `strcat` looks fishy, look at the section about the return value: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat

Comment: Also don't cast the return value of `malloc`.

Comment: `newnode->item.string = (char *)newnode + sizeof(log_t);` - Do you really understand what you are doing?

Comment: @Serge Not really no. I'm trying to learn and this addmsg function is part of template in the textbook I am following

Comment: If that code is really copied from this book then I would recommend you to find another book. Although, this code might be working properly, it does not show good practices and definitely not the best sample to learn the language.

Comment: Yeah its a really old book and that line is copied exactly from it. We have to use this template though so I don't know.

Comment: I think perhaps you should be adding the additional info (i.e.  executable name) into the data_t structure instead of modifying the API

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems bent on calculating the size of a memory buffer that would hold *both* the `log_t` node structure *and* the concatenated message parts, having the string pointer within the `data_t` member of the linked list node point within the single memory block, just passed the linked list node content, where the message is stored. In short, a single allocation holding both the node and the message.

That said, exploit the fact that there are standard library API's, notably [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) that can calculate formatted message buffer length requirements *for you*, and you can then skip most of the string management malaise in favor of the real purpose of this, managing the linked list structure *and* the dynamic message content with a single invoke to `malloc` (and by circumstance, a single invoke to `free()` when this fiasco needs to be undone):

- Determine the length of the formatted string data
- Allocate a buffer large enough to hold that data, *and* the structure that will precede it.
- Position the string pointer in the structure to the first `char` just *passed* the structure layout.
- Perform the formatted message dump into the memory pointed to by that string pointer.

The result is a single allocation of dynamic length, depending on the content of the message being formatted.

**Using `snprintf` Instead**

```
int addmsg(data_t data, const char *arg0)
{
    static const char fmt[] = "%s: Time: %s Error: %s";
    char stime[32] = ""; // per ctime docs, must be at least 26 chars
    int res = -1;

    // get time string, trim newline
    ctime_r(&data.time, stime);
    if (*stime)
        stime[strlen(stime)-1] = 0;

    // find needed message size
    int req =  snprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, data.string, stime, arg0);
    if (req > 0)
    {
        // include size of log record, formatted message, and terminator
        log_t *node = malloc(sizeof (log_t) + req + 1);
        if (node != NULL)
        {
            node->item.string = (char*)(node+1); // NOTE: see below
            node->item.time = data.time;
            node->next = NULL;
            snprintf(node->item.string, req+1, fmt, data.string, stime, arg0);

            // link into list
            if (!headPtr)
                headPtr = node;
            else
                tailPtr->next = node;
            tailPtr = node;

            // good return value
            res = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            perror("Failed to allocate memory for log mesage: ");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        perror("Failed to perform message formatting: ");
    }

    return res;
}
```

Everything above is fairly straight forward, save for possible `NOTE`, which I'll explain now. It uses *pointer arithmetic*. Given a pointer `node` of some type `log_t*` the expression:

```
(node + 1)
```

calculates the *next* position in memory where a subsequent `log_t` object could reside, or the "one-past" memory position in the case of the end of a sequence. When we allocated our memory, we did so to a layout that looks like this:

```
node ---> |=== log_t ===|===== message text =====|
```

the expression `(node+1)`, using typed pointer arithmetic, give us:

```
node ---> |=== log_t ===|===== message text =====|
(node+1)-----------------^
```

which is then cast to `char*`, saved in `node->data.string` and used as the target for the final message formatting using `snprintf`. Short version: `node->item.string` points to the extra memory we allocated following the `log_t` structure pointed to by `node`.

That's it. The result is a single allocation to a linked list node that contains both the node management data, and also contains a pointer to the dynamic message string stored in the suffix memory of the single allocation past the `log_t` core data.

Answer (score 1):

If you replaced the `log_t` construction piece of `addmsg` with something perhaps like this you would get better results.  Your calculation of required memory size is a little off.  Might want to also avoid assuming things about memory with your malloc (i.e.  Allocating extra memory to store both a structure and the contents of a pointer member of that structure could easily get you into trouble)

```
...
log_t *newnode = NULL;
void *vp = NULL;
if (NULL == (vp = malloc(sizeof(log_t)))) {
    perror("malloc failed (sizeof(log_t))");
    return -1;
}
newnode = (log_t *)vp;
newnode->item.time = data.time;

char *timeCode = ctime(&newnode->item.time);
int msgsize = strlen(": Time: Error: ")
            + strlen(arg0)
            + strlen(timeCode)
            + strlen(data.string)
            + 1;
if (NULL == (vp = malloc(msgsize))) {
    perror("malloc failed (msgsize)");
    free(newnode);
    return -1;
}
newnode->item.string = (char *)vp;
sprintf(newnode->item.string, "%s: Time: %s Error: %s", arg0, timeCode, data.string);
...
```